# how to check-out document in document library programmatically in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2007, document

how to set a document in check-in/out mode programmatically by using webservices or objetmodel in sharepoint

Answer (score 3):

You need [SPListItem.File.CheckOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.checkout.aspx) / [SPListItem.File.CheckIn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.checkin.aspx) from the object model. I don't know how to do this using the web service though.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [CheckInFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.checkinfile.aspx) and [CheckOutFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.checkoutfile.aspx) web methods of the [Lists webservice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.aspx).  The calls are pretty straight forward.  Hope this helps.