# Open a sharepoint libriary document with edit privliages

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-word

I have a WCF service running on the sharepoint server that will generate a document in a library and return its uri. I have a client application that calls the WCF service and launches word with edit privileges of the document that was just generated. However if I just pass word the URI of the document it will open the document in Read-Only mode. Trying to save back to the server overwriting the old file gives the error saying the document is Read-Only when saving.

How do I, from code, launch word with the ability to save changes back in to the file it opened on the sharepoint server?

Note: This is not a permissions issue, if I manually go in to the sharepoint site I have rights to click on the document and open as edit.

EDIT: Ok, So I think I know how to do it (I am going to make a dll and have rundll.exe launch word and do the babysitting). However I still would like to know if there are any other solutions than manually checking in and out the document.

Comment: Are checkins enabled on the library?  Are you checking the document out before opening it?

Comment: @Kyle, how to I check (via sharepoint designer if need be) if checkins are enabled?

Comment: @Kyle Trauberman, I think they enabled are but we are not using them.

Comment: See my answer.  Because checkins are enabled, the read-only flag is set on the document when you open it.  Checking the file out will clear the flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not need to check out the document, what I found out is I needed to launch `iexplore.exe` pointing at the URI using the following code.

```
Process.Start("iexplore.exe", ((FileDetails)e.Result).Address);
```

where `FileDetails` is the custom object the WCF service is returning and `.Address` is the URI of the document.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out the document before opening it.

```
SPListItem item = GetListItem();
item.File.CheckOut();
```

[how to check-out document in document library programmatically in sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431397/how-to-check-out-document-in-document-library-programmatically-in-sharepoint)

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/09/05/programmatically-check-incheck-out-documents-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: How is office doing it? I opened a document for edit on my machine from in sharepoint then another person looked at the library and it appeared not to be checked out, he could open it also but he got a warning saying the file is in use on the server. Is office doing that checkin/checkout itself or is it doing something different? I would really perfer not to need to include the sharepoint namespace on my client app if I do not need to. EDIT: I see i can use the REST methods built in to list but I would still perfer not managing it if I do not have to.

Comment: Will I need to babysit the office connection and check in the file by hand when it closes or will it do it itself. I am just concerned about people closing my app before they close word.

Comment: I know this is a old answer of yours, but I found a solution that solves the check out issue, see my [posted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9163074/80274).